TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
Разрабатываю приложение на next js + neo4j + sigma js
Всего 2 страницы:

Страница с input и кнопкой "Искать".
Страница '/search?query=123', на которой отображается граф связей (результат запроса к neo4j).

Граф строится с помощью библиотеки sigma js (точнее react-sigma https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sigma).
Связь с Neo4j работает корректно.
Проблема в том, что при нажатии на кнопку "Искать" вылезает следующая ошибка (даже 2):


Далее, при обновлении страницы граф отображается корректно.
Логически я понял, что проблема происходит во время рендеринга страницы (а именно графа) на стороне клиента. Не знаю, как исправить.
Начальная страница:
import Form from "next/form";
    
    export default function Home() {
      return (
        <Form action="/search">
          <input name="query" />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </Form>
      );
    }

Страница "/search":
import getSearchResults from "@/app/search/search";
import ResultGraph from "@/app/search/resultGraph";

export default async function Page({
  searchParams,
}: {
  searchParams: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined };
}) {
  const { query } = await searchParams;
  const results = await getSearchResults(query);

  return (
    <div>
      <ResultGraph resultSearch={results} />
    </div>
  );
}

компонент, отображающий граф:
(здесь для примера указан тестовый граф)
"use client";

import { Sigma, RandomizeNodePositions, RelativeSize } from "react-sigma";

export default function ResultGraph(resultSearch) {
  let myGraph = {
    nodes: [
      { id: "n1", label: "Alice" },
      { id: "n2", label: "Rabbit" },
    ],
    edges: [{ id: "e1", source: "n1", target: "n2", label: "SEES" }],
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Это будущий граф!</h1>
      <Sigma graph={myGraph} settings={{ drawEdges: true, clone: false }}>
        <RelativeSize initialSize={15} />
        <RandomizeNodePositions />
      </Sigma>
    </div>
  );
}

Дополнительно, не уверен, связаны ли эти вещи, но даже после обновления и якобы корректного отображения, в консоль падает ошибка 500

Помогите, пожалуйста. Спасибо!

Этот вопрос похож на: Почему возникает ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined or null (reading ***). Если вы уверены что это не так, нажмите [edit], дайте ясно понять, чем ваш вопрос отличается от дубликата и/или почему ответы на него не помогают решить вашу проблему.

Is not a function - ошибки на скрине и код не соответствуют друг другу. В коде нет обращения к 0 и нет вызова функции

@SwaD все правильно говорите, из-за несоответсвия ошибки и кода я и не могу понять, в чем проблема, ошибка связана с библиотекой почему-то

@SwaD в указанном вами вопросе нет сведений про react, там чистый js, а в моем случае ошибка скорее всего связана с генерацией странички

React это javaScript библиотека

@SwaD вы говорите мне обратить внимание на вопрос, где люди обращаются к несуществующим объектам и получают такую ошибку. Где вы видите, что я обращаюсь к таким объектам? Нигде. Поэтому я не знаю, в чем ошибка. Давайте подождем кого-то, кто знает.
